# Windows C/C++ printf/wprintf string to Python conversion?

Tags: python, printf

I have a lot of Windows printf/wprintf [format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx) and would like to either convert or use them in python. Are there any libraries / methods / code snippets that would do the expansion or convert to [PEP-3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101)?

Comment: Could you include some examples of what your format strings are? It might be relevant to know how much of the spec they use.

Comment: What formats are you using that are not covered by Python's string `%` operator?

Comment: I don't have any control over the format strings - I am essentially looking to reimplement FormatMessageW which expands Windows event logs - takes data and combines with relevant string from a DLL. Mostly I've unseen %1, %2, %s and %d in use